# Acmella oleracea (Szechuan buttons) - active chemical for mouth sensation?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, extracts

I am looking to begin growing Acmella oleracea (Szechuan buttons). I would like to use them directly, and also make extracts specifically to maximize the taste/oral stimulation effect. Apparently there are a ton of different active chemicals.

So does anyone know what chemical(s) causes the licking a 9volt battery/buzzing teeth/foaming mouth sensations?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acmella_oleracea) on Acmella oleracea, I get [Spilanthol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spilanthol) as the major compound in Jambu, an extract of the plant used culinarily for exactly the sensation you describe.